# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] SQLDriverConnect: -1044

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] SQLDriverConnect: -1044 [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Not a valid file name.' in C:\xampp\htdocs\img\config.php:15 
Stack trace: 

#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\img\config.php(15): PDO->__construct('odbc:Driver={Mi...') 
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\img\index.php(9): require_once('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...') 
#2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\img\config.php on line 15
```

I keep seeing this error but i can't see waht the problem i am using a ms access database requirement i really nee to create a role based access control thanks in advance

this is the code:

```
error_reporting( E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_NOTICE );
ob_start();
session_start();

$database = "C:\xampp\htdocs\img\multi-admin.mdb";
$DB = new PDO("odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};Dbq=$database;Uid=Admin");

define('PROJECT_NAME', 'Create Multi admin using php mysql and bootstrap library');
$dboptions = array(
              PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => FALSE, 
              PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, 
              PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
              PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8',
            );

try {
  $DB = new PDO("odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};Dbq=$database;Uid=Admin");
} catch (Exception $ex) {
  echo $ex->getMessage();
  die;
}

require_once 'functions.php';

//get error/success messages
if ($_SESSION["errorType"] != "" && $_SESSION["errorMsg"] != "" ) {
    $ERROR_TYPE = $_SESSION["errorType"];
    $ERROR_MSG = $_SESSION["errorMsg"];
    $_SESSION["errorType"] = "";
    $_SESSION["errorMsg"] = "";
}
?>
```

Comment: To start with, remove the comma after this line `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8',`

Comment: Then `catch` a `PDOException` and not just an `Exception`

Comment: Also you are not actually using the `$dboptions` array anywhere

Comment: Also check the manual for the correct parameters for a `new PDO(....)` [Manual is here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php)

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) _while testing_ right after your opening PHP tag for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to see if it yields anything.

Comment: Thank you going to try it .